# how can i install shield project

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, installation

how can i create setup for my program that i wrote by c# and used sql server 2005 and used designer report....
this program that i write with c# has a folder include pictures audio and sub folders that need to install on another pc that want to use this program  .
how can i create setup for it with install shield ... i have install shield application on version 10   that doesn't support .net4 . please help me . 
when i create setup .. my program can be run by all information like data base and pictures and ..... can't be perform . i can upload my program if you want to help me . thanks all;

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use an alternative? Microsoft seem to be putting a lot of weight behind WiX http://wixtoolset.org/ for building installers (it's used for Visual Studio and Office).

There is also a tutorial at http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/ , and a lot of knowledge here on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix?sort=newest